# JPA criteriabuilder where statement

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, criteria

I would like to achieve the following where statement in my CriteriaQuery.

```
  (Event.time >= NOW() 
     OR (Event.time >= '$clubHours' && (`EventSelectType`.`type`='cafe' || `EventSelectType`.`type`='DJ')) 
     OR (Event.endtime >= NOW() && (`EventSelectType`.`type`='festival' OR `EventSelectType`.`type`='dj' OR `EventSelectType`.`type`='cafe')))
```

I tried the following ;

```
eQr.where(
        cB.or(
            cB.or(
                    cB.greaterThanOrEqualTo(eventRoot.<Date>get("time"), curDate)   
                ),
            cB.or(
                    cB.and(
                    cB.greaterThanOrEqualTo(eventRoot.<Date>get("time"), cal.getTime())
                    ),
                        cB.or(
                                cB.equal(eventType.<String>get("type"), "cafe"),
                                cB.equal(eventType.<String>get("type"), "DJ")
                                )
                ),
            cB.or(
                    cB.and(
                    cB.greaterThanOrEqualTo(eventRoot.<Date>get("endtime"), curDate)
                    ),
                        cB.or(
                                cB.equal(eventType.<String>get("type"), "festival"),
                                cB.equal(eventType.<String>get("type"), "DJ"),
                                cB.equal(eventType.<String>get("type"), "cafe")
                                )
                )
        ),
        cB.equal(eventRoot.<Integer>get("id"), eventID),
        cB.equal(eventRoot.<Integer>get("active"), 1)
        );
```

But all this generates is one big OR statement

```
(event0_.time>=? or event0_.time>=? or eventselec13_.type=? or eventselec13_.type=? or event0_.endtime>=? or eventselec13_.type=? or eventselec13_.type=? or eventselec13_.type=?)
```

How could I get the result I'm looking for?

EDIT

I currently have this

```
Predicate eventTypeIscafeORDJ = cB.or(
        cB.equal(eventType.<String>get("type"), "cafe"),
        cB.equal(eventType.<String>get("type"), "DJ")
    );
Predicate eventTypeIsFestivalDJORCafe = cB.or(
        cB.equal(eventType.<String>get("type"), "cafe"),
        cB.equal(eventType.<String>get("type"), "DJ"),
        cB.equal(eventType.<String>get("type"), "festival")
        );

    Predicate timeGreaterOrEqualTo = cB.greaterThanOrEqualTo(eventRoot.<Date>get("time"), cal.getTime());
    Predicate endTimeGreaterOrEqualTo = cB.greaterThanOrEqualTo(eventRoot.<Date>get("endtime"), curDate);
    Predicate equalToId = cB.equal(eventRoot.<Integer>get("id"), eventID);

    eQr.where(timeGreaterOrEqualTo, cB.or( cB.and( timeGreaterOrEqualTo, eventTypeIscafeORDJ ), cB.and(endTimeGreaterOrEqualTo, eventTypeIsFestivalDJORCafe )), equalToId);
```

Which outputs

```
where event0_.time>=? and (event0_.time>=? and (eventselec13_.type=? or eventselec13_.type=?) or event0_.endtime>=? and (eventselec13_.type=? or eventselec13_.type=? or eventselec13_.type=?)) and event0_.id=633188
```

But it has to be

```
where (event0_.time>=? OR (event0_.time>=? and (eventselec13_.type=? or eventselec13_.type=?)) or (event0_.endtime>=? and (eventselec13_.type=? or eventselec13_.type=? or eventselec13_.type=?))) and event0_.id=633188
```

It still isn't exactly what I want and I cant seem to get it work the way I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with your obvious, first problem:

```
Event.time >= '$clubHours' && (`EventSelectType`.`type`='cafe' || `EventSelectType`.`type`='DJ'))
```

This should be constructed as

```
cB.and(
    cB.greaterThanOrEqualTo(eventRoot.<Date>get("time"), cal.getTime()), 
    cB.or(
        cB.equal(eventType.<String>get("type"), "cafe"),
        cB.equal(eventType.<String>get("type"), "DJ")
    )
), ...
```

Instead you have:

```
cB.and(
    cB.greaterThanOrEqualTo(eventRoot.<Date>get("time"), cal.getTime())
),
cB.or(
    cB.equal(eventType.<String>get("type"), "cafe"),
    cB.equal(eventType.<String>get("type"), "DJ")
)
```

So, basically, you need to be sure to look at your parentheses and not your indenting in order to understand what your code is doing. As a side note, you would be better off constructing this predicate in steps so your code is easier to read and understand. E.g.:

```
Predicate eventTypeIscafeORDJ = cB.or(
    cB.equal(eventType.<String>get("type"), "cafe"),
    cB.equal(eventType.<String>get("type"), "DJ")
);
Predicate timeGreaterOrEqualTo = cB.greaterThanOrEqualTo(eventRoot.<Date>get("time"), cal.getTime());
eQr.where( cB.and( timeGreaterOrEqualTo, eventTypeIscafeORDJ ) );
```

The database is almost always the slower part of the code and the optimizer will probably make the same runtime out or either set of code, so you should make it easier on yourself and others. Further, this is the time tested way of debugging a coding problem, especially when you see all those parens.

Comment: Thanks alot! You definitely pointed me in the right direction however I still can't seem to get it to work the way I want it to.

Comment: Start simple, build up, figure out where you're going wrong.

Comment: I'm almost there I just can't figure out the last bit.